# how to change flex item's size according to its content

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I have 2 containers. one for pictures and one for the table.
I want each container to change its height depending on the number of pictures and the number of table rows.

The upper picture's container should expand up to 2 rows (I did it with max-height) and become scrollable if there is a third row or more.
The bottom table's container should expand until the rest of the screen's height and then become scrollable.

BUT, if the picture's container has one row I want the table to expand up to the maximum height.

ALSO, I don't want the picture's second row to be cut by the table (unfortunately this is what happening right now).

This is what I did so far, close to the desired behavior but still not working as I wanted. I prefer to use only CSS for the solution.

here is my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/shts86/pen/wvzObJN)

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="pic-container">
    <div class="pic">picture</div>
    <div class="pic">picture</div>
    <div class="pic">picture</div>
    <div class="pic">picture</div>
    <div class="pic">picture</div>
    <div class="pic">picture</div>
    <div class="pic">picture</div>
    
  </div>
  <div class="table-container">
    <div class="table">
      <table>
        <tbody id="tbody">
        <tr><td>my</td><td>life</td><td>for</td><td>Auir</td</tr>
        <tr><td>my</td><td>life</td><td>for</td><td>Auir</td</tr>
        <tr><td>my</td><td>life</td><td>for</td><td>Auir</td</tr>
        <tr><td>my</td><td>life</td><td>for</td><td>Auir</td</tr>
        <tr><td>my</td><td>life</td><td>for</td><td>Auir</td</tr>
        
        
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.main {
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px;
  background: pink;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.pic-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 304px; /* 2 pic + borders*/

}

.table-container {
  background-color: lightsalmon;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-height: calc(600px - 152px);
}

.pic {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.table {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td {
  padding: 10px;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

[image: the table goes over the second picture row]

the table goes over the second picture row - bad

[image: this is how I want it to behave]

this is how I want it to behave -> any idea?

[image: example of how it behaves when there is one row]

example of how it behaves when there is one row - good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me. The most important part is changing the main div display form flex to grid: `display: grid; grid-template-rows: min-content auto;` And move `overflow: auto;` from the table tag to table-container class.

```
.main {
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px;
  background: pink;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: min-content auto;
}

.pic-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 304px; /* 2 pic + borders*/

}

.table-container {
  background-color: lightsalmon;
  overflow: auto;
}

.pic {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.table {
  height: 100%;
}

table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td {
  padding: 10px;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: yes! this is exactly the way I wanted it to behave. thank you  @Szabó Sebestyén!!